# How to get URI when using Spotify SDK for Android?

Tags: android, uri, spotify

I have followed the example and get following URI's. However I want to play more tracks. From the javadoc, URIs can be:

```
Single track
Playlists
Albums
Artists
Playlist folder
Radio
Toplist
```

How can I get the `URIs`?

```
private static final String PLAY_URI = "spotify:track:2TpxZ7JUBn3uw46aR7qd6V";
@SuppressWarnings("SpellCheckingInspection")
private static final String TEST_SONG_URI = "spotify:track:6KywfgRqvgvfJc3JRwaZdZ";
@SuppressWarnings("SpellCheckingInspection")
private static final String TEST_SONG_MONO_URI = "spotify:track:1FqY3uJypma5wkYw66QOUi";
@SuppressWarnings("SpellCheckingInspection")
private static final String TEST_SONG_48kHz_URI = "spotify:track:3wxTNS3aqb9RbBLZgJdZgH";
@SuppressWarnings("SpellCheckingInspection")
private static final String TEST_PLAYLIST_URI = "spotify:user:spotify:playlist:2yLXxKhhziG2xzy7eyD4TD";
@SuppressWarnings("SpellCheckingInspection")
private static final String TEST_ALBUM_URI = "spotify:album:2lYmxilk8cXJlxxXmns1IU";
@SuppressWarnings("SpellCheckingInspection")
private static final String TEST_QUEUE_SONG_URI = "spotify:track:5EEOjaJyWvfMglmEwf9bG3";
```